# Pandas slice by [ ] throws index out of bounds error, but .ix doesnt

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

ive been trying to make a function that generates stratified samples from a dataset (as sklearn doesn't have such a function) and I've come up with one.

The function below generates the indices and i was hoping to slice the original dataset with that, but for some reason when it gets to the

```
sampleData = dataset[indexes]
```

line, it throws a

```
IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds
```

error. However,

```
sampleData = dataset.ix[indexes]
```

works. However, I have a feeling this is wrong and screwing up my later processes. Anyone have any idea? :)

Here's the full code up to that point:

```
def stratifiedSampleGenerator(dataset,target,subsample_size=0.1):
    print('Generating stratified sample of size ' + str(round(len(dataset)*subsample_size,2)))
    dic={}
    indexes = np.array([])
    # find number of classes in sample
    for label in target.unique(): 
         labelSize = len(target[target==label]) 
         dic[label] = int(labelSize * subsample_size)
    # make a dataset of size sizeSample with ratio of classes in dic
    for label in dic:
        classIndex = target[target==label].index #obtain indexes of class
        counts = dic[label]   #get number of times class occurs
        newIndex = np.random.choice(classIndex,counts,replace=False)
        indexes = np.concatenate((indexes,newIndex),axis=0)

    indexes = indexes.astype(int)
    sampleData = dataset[indexes] #throws error
    sampleData =  dataset.ix[indexes] #doesnt
```

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

In fact, `sklearn` **does have** a way to split a dataset in a stratified fashion.

Wouldn't something like this be enough in your case?

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

dataset = ['A']*100 + ['B']*20 + ['C']*10
target = [0]*100 + [1]*20 + [2]*10
X_fit,X_eval,y_fit,y_eval= train_test_split(dataset,target,test_size=0.1,stratify=target)
print X_eval.count('A') # output: 10
print X_eval.count('B') # output: 2
print X_eval.count('C') # output: 1
```

Check the documentation here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html

Comment: Hiya, what im looking for is a stratified sample. If im not wrong, that function in sklearn generates stratified folds for the entire dataset. So the sizes will still be the same.

Eg, original dataset: 100A 20B 10C

stratified sample: 10A 2B 1C

Comment: in my example, `X_eval` and `y_eval` will contain a stratified subsample of size 0.1*total_dataset_size. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: just updated the example, you can run it right away, also printed the outputs so you can see that it takes the subsample size but it preserves proportions

Comment: Ah. Well I suppose that is true! I was blinded by the length of X_fit. Thank you for your easy way! :) Out of curiosity, do you why the function I made wont work? :)

Comment: I think it's just the way indexing is done in Pandas, you could also have used `dataset.loc[indexes]` or `dataset.iloc[indexes]` and would have worked. Just the way selecting data by index is done.

Comment: But seriously, I recommend using the `train_test_split` as it is widely tested. Moreover, in the example I passed a simple array of data but you can also feed the `sklearn`s function with a Pandas DataFrame and the output will preserve the index of the selected data. I mean, it performs a random split but it keeps the index of the selected sample so you can trace it back with the original dataset. Good luck!